# Why can't I see witness in the failover cluster manager snap-in?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_hadr_cluster_members
```

This query shows me 2 nodes and 1 file share witness.

However, when I open the wsfc cluster manager snap-in, then click on Role, select the role, I cannot see the witness. Am I looking in wrong place for witness?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are looking at the wrong place in cluster manager snap-in.
On the snap-in, click on the cluster name, and you should be able to see it in two places.

See the image below:

[image]

You can also use the PowerShell command `Get-ClusterQuorum` to get information about the witness. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterquorum?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

Comment: Ok so the witness is shared across all roles (assuming there are multiple roles)?

Comment: Witness has nothing to do directly with roles. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum).